# how to change background image of windows store application in c# code?

Tags: c#, windows, windows-store-apps, windows-store

I want to change the background image of a windows store app using C#.
I'm looking to change the background image similar to the following pseudo code:

```
This.Background.ImageSource= "dracula-128.png";
```

Comment: This.Background.ImageSource= "dracula-128.png";
I need something like that.

Comment: all I need is just a one line of code that changes the background image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to create an `ImageBrush`, set its `ImageSource` property, and then assign that to the background. (Code updated based on comment)

```
//BitmapImage class is within this namespace
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging;    

ImageBrush ib = new ImageBrush();
ib.ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"ms-appx:///dracula-128.png", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));   
this.Background = ib;
```

Comment: Yes, this solution works on WPF applications, but it does not work on windows store apps and giving that error message.
Error 1 The type or namespace name 'BitmapImage' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @user1935611 - You need to use add `using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging;`